# Pandas Dataframe growing in rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (which may grow in rows and Info columns):

```
City    Country   Info1  Info2
BCN      Spain    3      5.6   
Moscow   Russia   4      7
```

I'm trying to split the information as follows :

```
[
{Info1: 3,
 City: BCN,
 Country: Spain},

{Info2: 5.6,
 City: BCN,
 Country: Spain},

{Info1: 4,
 City: Moscow,
 Country: Russia},

{Info2: 7,
 City: Moscow,
 Country: Russia}
]
```

This works:

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'city':["BCN", "Moscow"], 
        'country': ["Spain", "Russia"], 
        'inf_1':[3, 5],
        'inf_2':[4,7]} 

#we make the dict a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 

# We make a list of the indicators
columns = list(df)[2:]
j=0
i=0


for rows in df.itertuples():
    for col in columns:
        print(" ")
        print("city: " + str(rows.city) )
        print("country: " + str(rows.country))
        print("ind_id: "+ str(columns[j]))
        print("value: "+ str(df[col][i]))
        print(" ")
        j=j+1
    j=0
    i=i+1
```

However, this result doesn't seem beautiful to me. Since I'm quite new to Pandas, is there anyway to make a more elegant code getting the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay with a small tweak in your output, you can use `melt` and `to_dict` directly to get separate dictionaries for each info:

```
>>> df.melt(['City', 'Country']).to_dict('r')
```

```
[{'City': 'BCN', 'Country': 'Spain', 'value': 3.0, 'variable': 'Info1'},
 {'City': 'Moscow', 'Country': 'Russia', 'value': 4.0, 'variable': 'Info1'},
 {'City': 'BCN', 'Country': 'Spain', 'value': 5.6, 'variable': 'Info2'},
 {'City': 'Moscow', 'Country': 'Russia', 'value': 7.0, 'variable': 'Info2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-Pandas-specific solution, this `split_rows` function works for any iterable of namedtuples (or if you change the `rd = ...` line, anything that can be dictified).

```py
import pandas as pd


def split_rows(namedtuple_iterable, cols):
    for row in namedtuple_iterable:
        rd = row._asdict()
        cs = [(col, rd.pop(col)) for col in cols]
        for key, value in cs:
            yield {**rd, key: value}


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "city": ["BCN", "Moscow"],
        "country": ["Spain", "Russia"],
        "inf_1": [3, 5],
        "inf_2": [4, 7],
    }
)


for sr in split_rows(df.itertuples(), ("inf_1", "inf_2")):
    print(sr)
```

outputs

```
{'Index': 0, 'city': 'BCN', 'country': 'Spain', 'inf_1': 3}
{'Index': 0, 'city': 'BCN', 'country': 'Spain', 'inf_2': 4}
{'Index': 1, 'city': 'Moscow', 'country': 'Russia', 'inf_1': 5}
{'Index': 1, 'city': 'Moscow', 'country': 'Russia', 'inf_2': 7}
```

Comment: Interesting! But is it a good idea to use private member `_asdict()` ?

Comment: Yes. It's not really private, it's just named like that so `namedtuple`s may have a "user" member called `asdict`. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict

Comment: That's interesting - some mix up in the notation then :}

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for but nice code!

Comment: @Alvaro Aside from `Index` being there, what's wrong with the result?

Comment: The datatable may grow in columns as well

Comment: Right – then you'd pass the columns, say, figuring them out based on `list(df.columns)`, you want to "explode" into `split_rows` :)