# From MongoDB dictionary to Dataframe mapping

Tags: pandas, mongodb, dataframe, dictionary

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142639/pandas-dataframe-growing-in-rows-and-columns/59142775?noredirect=1#comment104512468_59142775) I transform a DF into a list of dicts to upload to MongoDB.

Now I'm doing the opposite work. From a MongoDB query I can download a list of dicts containing the following info:

```
[
{Info1: 3,
 City: BCN,
 Country: Spain},

{Info2: 5.6,
 City: BCN,
 Country: Spain},

{Info1: 4,
 City: Moscow,
 Country: Russia},

{Info2: 7,
 City: Moscow,
 Country: Russia}
]
```

Now i want to create a table as follows:

```
City    Country   Info1  Info2
BCN      Spain    3      5.6   
Moscow   Russia   4      7
```

The way I'm doing it right now is as follows:

```
  def generate_excel(ind_type):
     # first add columns
     columns = ["City", "Country"]

     # then  find all indictors filtered
     indicators = []
     for indicator in CUSTOMERS_COLLECTION.find().distinct("ID"):
         indicators.append(indicator)

     # then add the indicators in column
     columns = columns + indicators

     # First find all Ciudades
     cities = CUSTOMERS_COLLECTION.find()

      rows_list = []
     for ciudad in cities.distinct("City"):
        indicators = CUSTOMERS_COLLECTION.find({"City": ciudad})
        dict_ind = {}
        # then we create a dict of the indicators. It will be the row
        for indicator in indicators:
            dict_ind[indicator["ID"]] = indicator["Valor"]
            dict_ind["Country"] = indicator["Country"]
            dict_ind["City"] = indicator["City"]

     df_ = pd.DataFrame(rows_list, columns=columns)
     return df_
```

As in my previous question, this works but it seems not optimized at all. Is there any functionality from MongoDB or from DF that allows mapping the dictionary correctly?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% this will work for you, but in the past I've been able to simply transform mongo queries into data frames. For example:

```
q1=db.collection.find(#add whatever filters you need)
df= pd.DataFrame(q1)
```

Please tell me if this works.